# Keytool -import ssl certificate from personal CA on jboss 4.0.5 server

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, jboss

What i am trying to do for a few days already, and it drives me crazy, is to make a java website based on **jboss 4.0.5** server to use ssl certificate(**https**). For this I'm following [these](https://dzone.com/articles/keytool-commandutility-to-generate-a-keystorecerti) instructions:

1. generating keystore (sha256withRSA) - though I used *-sigalg sha512withRSA* when generating
2. generating request and sending to my CA
3. CA is sending me 2 certs: **base64.cer** and **base64-chain.p7b**
4. a) Now I need to import my base64.cer into my keystore which gives me this error

   > *keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Failed to establish chain from reply*

   - the only way for this import to work is to use another alias (not the one of keystore) which is not the right thing to do
5. b)Because first way didn't work, now I'm trying to import *.p7b* file which gives me this error:

   > *keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Certificate chain in reply does not verify: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.10 Signature not available*

   - my CA has sha512 algorithm and that number from above error means **rsassaPss** Signature Algorithm

Because my CA has an intermediate I try to follow [these](https://www.sslsupportdesk.com/troubleshooting-advanced-tomcat-x509-failed-to-establish-chain-from-reply/) instructions and exporting root, intermediate as separate *.cer* files. When I try import **root.cer** gives me this error

> *keytool error: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.10 Signature not available*

Strange thing is that if I try to import intermediate certificate it's working though it has same algorithm (sha512)

I'm pretty desperate, I don't know what else I can do to make this work...Thanks in advance!

***Java version: 1.6.0_45 -  jboss 4.0.5***

Answer (score 0):

The problem was java version itself (java 6), so finally I installed jdk14 and I succeded to install with no problem the ***.p7b*** certificate sent by my CA.